# solve the equation of the following

Tags: systems-of-equations

the real number $a, b, c, d, e$ have some equations as follows

\begin{array}{lcl} ac=1 \\ ad+bc=-1 \\ ae+bd=1 \\ be=-6 \end{array}

how can I find the value of $a+b+c+d+e$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  To begin with surround math expressions with `$` signs.

Comment: What leads you to believe there's a unique solution?  You have $4$ nonlinear equations in $5$ unknowns.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have to find value of $(a+b)\times (c+d+e)$ instead?

Comment: @cosmo5 That's one of the steps, and my guess is that they asked for $a+b+c+d+e$ to hide that.

Comment: @CalvinLin, now that I see your answer, it was a nice setup! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, write out your working and thought process to demonstrate where you're at.)

**Hint:** $x^3 - x^2 + x - 6 = (x-2) ( x^2 + x + 3)$.

Comment: I know that (a+b)=5, (c+d+e)=-1 so the answer is 4.. But I dont understand why

Comment: @Butter How would you use the hint? How is it helpful? How does it relate to the initial conditions? E.g. where is the 6?

Comment: (ac)x^3+(ad+bc)x^2+(ae+bd)x+(be) and do I have to factorize this equation?

Comment: @Butter Right. The idea is to factorize it over the reals (and hope that there is a unique factorization)

Comment: wow Thank you so much...This is a brilliant idea. You're a genius!. But to be honest I don't know what to do after this...factorization  (ax+b)(cx^2+dx+e) How can I figure the a+b+c+d+e? does it mean that a=1, b=-2, c=1, d=1, e=3? How did u get this idea in thought? this questions seems to have no connection at all with factorization. How did u got the clue?

Comment: @Butter A) Note that the factorization is unique (over the reals) because the quadratic has no real roots. Hence we must have $ a = 1, b = -2, \ldots $.  B) From experience, and looking at the cross terms. C) As Cosmos pointed out, from the given equations, we have $(a+b) \times (c+d+e) = 1 -1 + 1 - 6 = -5$. This doesn't fix the values are yet (even if we assume they are integers), so how can we further manipulate this to get what we want? One possible way is to define $ (ax+b) \times (cx^2 + dx + e)$.